# Building CMake project with Boost libraries on GitHub Actions gives error "Could NOT find Boost"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, cmake, github-actions

I'm trying to build my CMake project on GitHub Actions workflow. Everything is working locally on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and building a Docker image, but not when using the same OS on GitHub Actions.

**The error is the following:**

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system filesystem thread
  date_time chrono regex serialization program_options)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:261 (find_package)
```

**My GitHub Actions workflow job:**

```
install:
    name: Install Dependencies
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: [ clean ]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install General
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libboost-all-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev gcc-11 g++-11 git cmake librocksdb-dev cron rpcbind libboost-system1.74.0 libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libboost-thread1.74.0 libboost-date-time1.74.0 libboost-chrono1.74.0 libboost-regex1.74.0 libboost-serialization1.74.0 libboost-program-options1.74.0 libicu70

  build:
    name: Build Target
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: [ install ]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Create Build Dir
        run: mkdir build
      - name: CMake
        run: cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-g0 -Os -fPIC -std=gnu++17" -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DBoost_ARCHITECTURE=-x64 ..
        working-directory: build
      - name: Make
        run: make -j$(nproc) --ignore-errors
        working-directory: build
```

**My CMake configuration of Boost:**

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem thread date_time chrono regex serialization program_options)
message(STATUS "Boost Found: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

When building it in a Docker container with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS it works without any problems.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

COPY . /usr/src/project_name
WORKDIR /usr/src/project_name

# install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      build-essential \
      libssl-dev \
      libffi-dev \
      python3-dev \
      gcc-11 \
      g++-11 \
      git \
      cmake \
      librocksdb-dev \
      libboost-all-dev \
      libboost-system1.74.0 \
      libboost-filesystem1.74.0 \
      libboost-thread1.74.0 \
      libboost-date-time1.74.0 \
      libboost-chrono1.74.0 \
      libboost-regex1.74.0 \
      libboost-serialization1.74.0 \
      libboost-program-options1.74.0 \
      libicu70

# create the build directory
RUN mkdir build
WORKDIR /usr/src/project_name/build

# build and install
RUN cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-g0 -Os -fPIC -std=gnu++17" .. && make -j$(nproc) --ignore-errors

WORKDIR /usr/src/project_name/build/src
```

All of the dependencies are installed on the GitHub runner with a job before. Any ideas why this might occur? Anyone else had this issue? I can post the CMake debug info if requested.

Comment: What does the _job before_ look like?

Comment: @M.Spiller Added it to the issue now.

Comment: The Gihub action runner ubuntu-22.04 does not contain the boost package by default. See [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/5490) for a list of installed packages. You need to install it as in your Docker image with `sudo apt-get -y install libboost-dev` before running CMake.

Comment: @vre Is `libboost-dev` different from `libboost-all-dev` that I'm currently installing?

Comment: According to [here](https://installati.one/ubuntu/22.04/libboost-dev/) it should be equivalent to your entire boost installation but maybe it's simple a shorter way to do the same.

Comment: @vre did a new run with `libboost-dev` and the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure that the two jobs are running on the same machine? I think, on github.com you will get a fresh runner for every job.

Comment: @M.Spiller That I have no idea about to be honest. This was new to me that there might be a new runner for every job. I thought the same workflow should be on the same. Hmm.

Comment: @M.Spiller That worked! Thanks for pointing that out, I had no idea that it worked like that. If you add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

github.com will give you a fresh runner for every job.

See here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#using-a-github-hosted-runner for details.

Thus it is not possible to prepare the machine in one job and use it in a later job.

You should move the installation of the needed packages inside your build job.

In case you need to exchange artifacts, like binaries from one job to a later job, you should take a look at the github actions [upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) and [download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot! Just one question if you might have an idea how to fix this in my GitHub actions workflow. If I wanted to run unit tests in another job, how can I move these target files across? Should I store them somewhere?

Comment: @MarcusCvjeticanin That is typically done by using the github actions [upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) and [download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact).
You basically upload your binary at the end of the build job and download it at the beginning of the test job. I will extend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a fragment to try. My `Github` action runner for `ubuntu-latest` looks as follows (you probably want to replace the `install` target in `CMake` build command with `all`.

```
jobs:
  ubuntu-build:
    name: Ubuntu Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Checkout submodules
        run: git submodule update --init --recursive
      - name: Create build directory and run CMake
        run: |
          sudo apt-get -y update
          sudo apt-get -y install libboost-dev
          cmake -S . -B cmake_build_dir -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=cmake_install_dir
      - name: Build project
        run: cmake --build cmake_build_dir --target install --config Release -- -j4
      - name: Run tests
        run:  ctest -C Release -VV
        working-directory: cmake_build_dir
      - name: Create Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: Ubuntu-Artifacts
          path: cmake_install_dir/
        if: always()
```